# How to implement Uniscribe for Linux

Tags: linux, icu, pango, harfbuzz, uniscribe

I'm trying to implement Uniscribe for Linux to display complex text, such as Arabic. It seems a huge task to do.

What I need to do is to implement the APIs below:

1. Check if the string is Complex.
2. Get string width.
3. Get next segment.
4. Get next break.
5. ...

I want to use/refer to open source code to do it.

I have read `HarfBuzz` source code for weeks, but didn't get the APIs for them. Is it feasible to use ONLY `HarfBuzz` to implement them?
It seems I should use `Pango`, but I can't do it due to its license. Is there any substitution? MIT license is OK.

Is `ICU` helpful to me?

Comment: The question seems a bit broad (to me). Maybe start with [uniscribe linux site:github.com](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=uniscribe+linux+site:github.com)

Answer (score 1):

Check out https://github.com/HOST-Oman/libraqm as smallest thing that might meet your needs.